# Align divs along image vertically

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS/JS summed up in a codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdwLGm

HTML:

```
<div id="blockcart-wrapper">
  <div class="blockcart cart-preview">
    <div class="header">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="#">
        <img class="cart-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" onclick="toggleClass()">

      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="shopping-cart-body">
      <div class="close"><a href="" onclick="toggleClass()">X</a></div>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">CART</div>
      <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product">
          <span class="prodcut-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100"></span>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="name-header">This is a very long test name</div>
            <div class="product-quantity-details">
              <span class="quantity">QTY</span>
              <span class="color-circle"></span>
              <span class="color">COLOR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-open">
              <span class="product-price">XX.XX</span>
              <span class="product-link"><a href="#">open</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="checkout">
        <div class="taxes">
          <span class="label">Taxes</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
          <span class="label">Total</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <button><a href="#">Checkout</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cart-preview {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.cart-preview a,
.cart-preview a:hover,
.cart-preview a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.cart-preview .header {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.cart-preview .body {
    visibility: visible;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: right 1s linear;
    right: -400px;
}

.cart-preview .body.open {
    visibility: visible;
    transition: right 1s linear;
    right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shopping-cart-body {
    font-family: 'IBMPlexSerif';
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .close{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    float: left;
}
.cart-preview .body .shopping-cart-header{
    font-family: 'IBMPlexSans';
    font-size: 45px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.cart-preview .body .products-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.product {
    display: flex;
}

.product>div {
    width: 50%;
}

.product .prodcut-image {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.product img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


.name-header{
        text-align: left;
    }

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-details {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}


.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before {
    content: ' \25CF';
    font-size: 30px;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: white;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 33px;
    color: black;
}

.cart-preview .product{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity:after{
    content: 'x'
}


.cart-preview .body .checkout>button {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    top: 13%;
    line-height: 14px;
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 205px;
    left: 25%;
}

.checkout .taxes{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 5%;
}

.checkout .cart-total{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 10%;
    float: left;
}

.cart-total .value {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: right;
}
.cart-total .value:after {
    content:'€'
}

.cart-total .label {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}


.taxes .value {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: right;
}

.taxes .label {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.taxes>hr{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-color: black;
}

.product-quantity-details{
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.product-details{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start
}

#blockcart-modal {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .1);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center
}

#blockcart-modal > div {
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

and the JavaScript (only contains one function):

```
function toggleClass() {
  document.getElementById('shopping-cart-body').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

So the goal is to align the items right of the picuture. The name (div with class `name-header` should always be at the 'top' level of the picture, the quantity (div with class `product-quantity-details` should be at the 'half' and the price (div with class `price-open` should be at the bottom. The alignment within the elements is fine, just the positioning is not working the way I want.
What I tried:  I tried using `position: absolute;` for the divs to align and then using `top:0;` for the name, `bottom:0;` for the price and `top: 50%;` for the quantity details. This was not really working.
Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, Open the snippet in full screen mode

I increased the height of the image to 300px for testing purpose only.

`justify-content:space-between;` will align the items by distributing space equally between children.

In your case name will be on top, product details in middle and price at the bottom

Add this to ur CSS

```
 .product-details{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content:space-between;
    }
```

```js
function toggleClass() {
  document.getElementById('shopping-cart-body').classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.cart-preview {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.cart-preview a,
.cart-preview a:hover,
.cart-preview a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.cart-preview .header {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.cart-preview .body {
    visibility: visible;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: right 1s linear;
    right: -400px;
}

.cart-preview .body.open {
    visibility: visible;
    transition: right 1s linear;
    right: 0px;
}

.cart-preview .body .shopping-cart-body {
    font-family: 'IBMPlexSerif';
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.cart-preview .body .close{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    float: left;
}
.cart-preview .body .shopping-cart-header{
    font-family: 'IBMPlexSans';
    font-size: 45px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.cart-preview .body .products-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.product {
    display: flex;
}

.product>div {
    width: 50%;
}

.product .prodcut-image {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.product img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px; /*For testing purpose*/
}


.name-header{
        text-align: left;
    }

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 0;
}

.cart-preview .body .products-container>.product-details {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}


.cart-preview .body .products-container .color-circle:before {
    content: ' \25CF';
    font-size: 30px;
}

.cart-preview .body .checkout {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: white;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 33px;
    color: black;
}

.cart-preview .product{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.product-quantity-details .quantity:after{
    content: 'x'
}


.cart-preview .body .checkout>button {
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    top: 13%;
    line-height: 14px;
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 205px;
    left: 25%;
}

.checkout .taxes{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 5%;
}

.checkout .cart-total{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 10%;
    float: left;
}

.cart-total .value {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: right;
}
.cart-total .value:after {
    content:'€'
}

.cart-total .label {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}


.taxes .value {
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: right;
}

.taxes .label {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.taxes>hr{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-color: black;
}

.product-quantity-details{
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.product-details{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

#blockcart-modal {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .1);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center
}

#blockcart-modal > div {
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<div id="blockcart-wrapper">
  <div class="blockcart cart-preview">
    <div class="header">
      <a rel="nofollow" href="#">
        <img class="cart-icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x20" onclick="toggleClass()">

      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="body" id="shopping-cart-body">
      <div class="close"><a href="" onclick="toggleClass()">X</a></div>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <div class="shopping-cart-header">CART</div>
      <div class="products-container">
        <div class="product">
          <span class="prodcut-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x100"></span>
          <div class="product-details">
            <div class="name-header">This is a very long test name</div>
            <div class="product-quantity-details">
              <span class="quantity">QTY</span>
              <span class="color-circle"></span>
              <span class="color">COLOR</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price-open">
              <span class="product-price">XX.XX</span>
              <span class="product-link"><a href="#">open</a></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="checkout">
        <div class="taxes">
          <span class="label">Taxes</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-total">
          <span class="label">Total</span>
          <span class="value">0</span>
        </div>
        <button><a href="#">Checkout</a></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, was about to write a comment about the stretched images when i saw the height: 300px in the img rule:D

Answer (score 0):

Add these two things too

```
.cart-preview .header {
    float: left;
}

.cart-preview .body {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: but that does not help to position the divs vertically along the left image?

Comment: go for vertical-align : center/top/bottom ;